# C# Fastest Way to Get Total Directory Size With 75,00 Files

Tags: c#, winapi, directory, pinvoke, filesize

I am looking for a faster way to get the total size of all files in subfolders with over 75,000 files with C#.  The following takes about 8 seconds on my laptop with an SSD drive.

```
 FileInfo[] files;
 long fileMBs;


 files = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
 foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
 {
     fileMBs += fi.Length;
 }
```

I looked into using Win32 CreateFile and GetFileSize, but could not find examples on how to call them from C#.  Would this be faster if called for each file given its full path?  If so, I do I use them from C#?  Is there a faster way?

Comment: If you want to call raw Win32 calls, look them up on _pinvoke.net_.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32

Comment: Not sure you'll go dramatically faster with p/invoke. p/invoke is what .NET already does undercover. This tool https://diskanalyzer.com/ (disclaimer: I'not related in any way) goes dramatically faster on NTFS because it directly parses NTFS structures. It's not open source. Maybe this could help https://github.com/LordMike/NtfsLib (untested)

Comment: You could use _.EnumerateFiles()_. This won't be faster, but you would get an interception point where you could visualize the progress and it wouldn't frozen your app.

Comment: I used pinvoke.net for CopyFileEx just a few days ago, but https://www.pinvoke.net/ returned a 404 all day yesterday and today.

Comment: I compared win32 `FindFirstFileEx` and `FindNextFile` in C++ with the `GetFiles` approach in C# and they did perform exactly the same. If you need a faster algorithm you have to set some constraints and make tradeoffs. For example on SSD's you could use multithreading for parallel file walking but this may reduce the speed on HDD's as they have to physically move the head. I implemented multithreading into the C++ approach and it went from ~6s for 415.000 files to ~1.5s on my SSD. Or if you require the user to have admin privileges you could use NTFS directly like Simon Mourier mentioned.

Comment: are you need enumerate files only in specified folder, or in it subfolders (recursive) too ? in any way this can be much more fast. i enumerate all files (recursive) in *"c:\\windows"* - here i have 137726 (137K) files and all take 860ms (so less than 1 second). "c:\\users" take 547 ms with 503K files. however this is on second run, after result cached. first run always much longer

Comment: @Stuntman11 *I implemented multithreading* in case recursive enum files in all subfolder i guess ? however here need not direct multithreading, but rather asynchronous I/O. and yes result depend from are disk have seek penalty

Comment: @RbMm I used the term "multithreading" because to my knowledge there is no explicit async api for `FindNextFile`. So your only option is to use multiple threads and bet on windows to implicitly use async io.

Comment: @Stuntman11 of course enumeration can asynchronous in direct sense. Need use NtQueryDirectoryFile. But my question was - are task enum files in single   or in all subfolders too ( here exist sense use asynchronous I/O ) case of single  is trivial at all

Comment: @RbMm I did not know that such a function existed in user mode. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it exist in user mode and support asynchronous enumeration. But i still can not understand - single  or with subfolders. Because i don't know c#/net at all

Comment: @RbMm `SearchOption.AllDirectories` means recursive in C#/dotnet :)

Answer (score 0):

if the disk have not [incurs a seek penalty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddstor/ns-ntddstor-_device_seek_penalty_descriptor) for speed up search we can do severel I/O request to disk at once and not wait in place, intil I/O is finished, but do asynchronous I/O. this possible do with `NtQueryDirectoryFile` api. open folder, bind it to IOCP (thread pool) and process results in callbacks, when I/O finished. handle at once several I/O requests

```
struct uIRP;

struct __declspec(novtable) uObject 
{
    HANDLE _M_hFile = 0;
    PTP_IO _M_Io = 0;
    LONG _M_dwRefCount = 1;

    virtual ~uObject()
    {
        if (_M_Io) TpReleaseIoCompletion(_M_Io); //CloseThreadpoolIo
        if (_M_hFile) NtClose(_M_hFile);
    }

    virtual void OnIoComplete(uIRP* irp, NTSTATUS status, ULONG_PTR dwBytes) = 0;

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_dwRefCount);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_M_dwRefCount))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }
};

struct uIRP : IO_STATUS_BLOCK
{
    uIRP* _M_pNext = 0;

    VOID OnIoComplete(
        _Inout_opt_ uObject* pObj,
        _In_ NTSTATUS status,
        _In_ ULONG_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered
        )
    {
        pObj->OnIoComplete(this, status, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
        pObj->Release();
    }

    static VOID NTAPI _S_OnIoComplete(
        _Inout_ PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE /*Instance*/,
        _Inout_opt_ PVOID Context,
        _In_ PVOID ApcContext,
        _In_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoSB,
        _In_ PTP_IO /*Io*/
        )
    {
        static_cast<uIRP*>(ApcContext)->OnIoComplete(reinterpret_cast<uObject*>(Context), IoSB->Status, IoSB->Information);
    }
};

struct FsDirectory;

struct Task 
{
    unsigned __int64 _M_Size;
    SRWLOCK _M_lock;
    PTP_POOL _M_Pool;
    uIRP* _M_irp;
    FsDirectory* _M_pObj;
    LONG _M_FileCount;
    LONG _M_FolderCount;
    LONG _M_ReparseCount;
    LONG _M_PendingCount;
    LONG _M_IoCount;
    LONG _M_FailCount;
    LONG _M_IoFailCount;
    LONG _M_dwRefCount = 1;
    ULONG _M_time = GetTickCount();
    ULONG _M_dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

    void* operator new(size_t s)
    {
        return LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED|LMEM_ZEROINIT, s);
    }

    void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        LocalFree(p);
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_dwRefCount);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_M_dwRefCount))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    BOOL Init(ULONG n)
    {
        do 
        {
            if (uIRP* irp = new uIRP)
            {
                irp->_M_pNext = _M_irp;
                _M_irp = irp;
                continue;
            }

            return FALSE;

        } while (--n);

        if (0 <= TpAllocPool(&_M_Pool, 0))
        {
            SYSTEM_INFO si;
            GetSystemInfo(&si);
            TpSetPoolMaxThreads(_M_Pool, si.dwNumberOfProcessors);
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    void push(uIRP* irp)
    {
        irp->_M_pNext = _M_irp;
        _M_irp = irp;
    }

    ~Task()
    {
        DbgPrint(">> %u %u/%u %u %I64u\r\n", 
            GetTickCount() - _M_time, _M_FileCount, _M_FolderCount, _M_ReparseCount, _M_Size);

        if (uIRP* irp = _M_irp)
        {
            do 
            {
                uIRP* p = irp;
                irp = irp->_M_pNext;
                delete p;
            } while (irp);
        }

        if (_M_Pool) TpReleasePool(_M_Pool);

        NtAlertThreadByThreadId((HANDLE)(ULONG_PTR)_M_dwThreadId);
    }

    void Start(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa);
};

struct __declspec(align(__alignof(SLIST_ENTRY))) FsDirectory : public uObject 
{
    enum { cbStruct = 0x10000 };

    Task* _M_pTask;
    FsDirectory* _M_pNext;
    PFILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION _M_pfdi;
    FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION _M_buf;

    inline static SLIST_HEADER _S_head;
    inline static PVOID _S_Mem;
    inline static ULONG _S_cb;

    static BOOL InitLookaSide (ULONG n)
    {
        RtlInitializeSListHead(&_S_head);

        union {
            PSLIST_ENTRY Entry;
            PVOID buf;
            ULONG_PTR up;
        };

        if (buf = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, _S_cb = n*cbStruct))
        {
            _S_Mem = buf;
            do 
            {
                RtlInterlockedPushEntrySList(&_S_head, Entry);
                up += cbStruct;
            } while (--n);

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    static void FreeLookaSide()
    {
        LocalFree(_S_Mem);
    }

    void* operator new(size_t /*s*/)
    {
        if (PVOID pv = RtlInterlockedPopEntrySList(&_S_head))
        {
            return pv;
        }

        return LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cbStruct);
    }

    void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        if ((ULONG_PTR)p - (ULONG_PTR)_S_Mem < _S_cb)
        {
            RtlInterlockedPushEntrySList(&_S_head, (PSLIST_ENTRY)p);
        }
        else
        {
            LocalFree(p);
        }
    }

    FsDirectory(Task* pTask) : _M_pTask(pTask)
    {
        pTask->AddRef();
    }

    ~FsDirectory()
    {
        _M_pTask->Release();
    }

    uIRP* pop(Task* pTask, PFILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION pfdi, uIRP* irp)
    {
        if (irp)
        {
            return irp;
        }

        AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&pTask->_M_lock);

        if (irp = pTask->_M_irp)
        {
            // pop IRP
            pTask->_M_irp = irp->_M_pNext;
        }
        else
        {
            // no more IRPs, push pending Directory
            AddRef();
            _M_pfdi = pfdi;
            _M_pNext = pTask->_M_pObj;
            pTask->_M_pObj = this;
        }

        ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&pTask->_M_lock);

        return irp;
    }

    void Process(Task* pTask, PFILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION pfdi, uIRP* irp)
    {
        FsDirectory* pObj;

        UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), _M_hFile, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

        ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

        do 
        {
            (ULONG_PTR&)pfdi += NextEntryOffset;

            if (pfdi->FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)
            {
                InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&pTask->_M_ReparseCount);
                continue;
            }

            if (pfdi->FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                switch (pfdi->FileNameLength)
                {
                case 2*sizeof(WCHAR): // ".."
                    if ('.' != pfdi->FileName[1])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case sizeof(WCHAR): // "."
                    if ('.' != pfdi->FileName[0])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (irp = pop(pTask, pfdi, irp))
                {
                    InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&pTask->_M_FolderCount);

                    if (pObj = new FsDirectory(pTask))
                    {
                        ObjectName.Buffer = pfdi->FileName;
                        ObjectName.MaximumLength = ObjectName.Length = (USHORT)pfdi->FileNameLength;

                        if (0 <= pObj->Create(&oa))
                        {
                            pObj->Enum(irp);
                            irp = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&pTask->_M_FailCount);
                        }

                        pObj->Release();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return ;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&pTask->_M_FileCount);
                InterlockedExchangeAddNoFence(&pTask->_M_Size, pfdi->EndOfFile.QuadPart);
            }

        } while (NextEntryOffset = pfdi->NextEntryOffset);

        if (irp = pop(pTask, 0, irp))
        {
            Enum(irp);
        }
    }

    virtual void OnIoComplete(uIRP* Irp, NTSTATUS status, ULONG_PTR /*dwBytes*/)
    {
        Task* pTask = _M_pTask;

        if (0 > status)
        {
            // we stop process directory

            if (STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES != status)
            {
                DbgPrint("!! %x\r\n", status);
                InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&pTask->_M_IoFailCount);
            }

            FsDirectory* pObj;

            AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&pTask->_M_lock);

            if (pObj = pTask->_M_pObj)
            {
                // exist pending directory
                pTask->_M_pObj = pObj->_M_pNext;
            }
            else
            {
                pTask->push(Irp);
            }

            ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&pTask->_M_lock);

            if (pObj)
            {
                if (PFILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION pfdi = pObj->_M_pfdi)
                {
                    pObj->Process(pTask, pfdi, Irp);
                }
                else
                {
                    pObj->Enum(Irp);
                }

                pObj->Release();
            }

            return;
        }

        Process(pTask, &_M_buf, Irp);
    }

    NTSTATUS Create(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
    {
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
        NTSTATUS status = NtOpenFile(&_M_hFile, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 
            FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT);

        TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON cbe;
        TpInitializeCallbackEnviron(&cbe);
        TpSetCallbackThreadpool(&cbe, _M_pTask->_M_Pool);
        return 0 > status ? status : TpAllocIoCompletion(&_M_Io, _M_hFile, uIRP::_S_OnIoComplete, this, &cbe);
    }

    void Enum(uIRP* irp)
    {
        AddRef();
        TpStartAsyncIoOperation(_M_Io);

        NTSTATUS status = NtQueryDirectoryFile(_M_hFile, 0, 0, irp, irp, 
            &_M_buf, cbStruct - offsetof(FsDirectory, _M_buf), 
            FileDirectoryInformation, FALSE, 0, FALSE);

        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_pTask->_M_IoCount);

        if (STATUS_PENDING == status)
        {
            InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_pTask->_M_PendingCount);
        }

        if (0 > status)
        {
            TpCancelAsyncIoOperation(_M_Io);
            irp->OnIoComplete(this, status, 0);
        }
    }
};

void Task::Start(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
{
    if (uIRP* irp = _M_irp)
    {
        if (FsDirectory* p = new FsDirectory(this))
        {
            if (0 <= p->Create(poa))
            {
                _M_irp = irp->_M_pNext;
                p->Enum(irp);
            }
            p->Release();
        }
    }
}

void TestEnum(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa, ULONG IoRequests)
{
    if (Task* pTask = new Task)
    {
        FsDirectory::InitLookaSide(0x100);

        if (pTask->Init(IoRequests))
        {
            pTask->Start(poa);
        }

        pTask->Release();

        NtWaitForAlertByThreadId(0, 0);

        FsDirectory::FreeLookaSide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a number of various tests.  The test folder was created by extracting a Drupal 10 tar.gz 3 times at different depths.  Each Drupal 10 installation has a bit over 25,000 files.

My limited excursion into Win32 was very slow, not a starter, and not considered worth my effort to understand why.

Using LINQ was the next slowest.

```
 var total = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(f => f.Length);
```

My testing, showed this is the fastest way, assuming path is the full path to a directory:

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 FileInfo[] total = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);      
 long totalMBs = 0;
 
  foreach ( var f in total )
  {
      totalMBs += f.Length;
  }
```

Don't have the energy to post all the testing code.  Tried LINQ, simple foreach as above, and a full recursion algorithm. The simple foreach was the fastest. Each test was run after a laptop shutdown for at least 30 seconds to clear the cache.  Simple timing using DateTime start, end.  Just an eyeball of what might make a difference.

[image]